# Assetion: how to assert None among other possible types

Tags: python

Python 3.8

This is a traceback. This is shown by Django web framework. But this doesn't matter.
The code is visible and so are the values of variables.

```
assert type(id) in [SafeString, None, int]

▼ Local vars
height  100
id  None
img <SvgImage: 3: Github logo>
width 100
```

Could you tell me why the code rose AssertionError?
And could you tell me how to refactor this code correctly?

Comment: `None` is not a type. `NoneType` is the type for `None`… But it's not exposed and shouldn't be used like that.

Comment: But how to use? Like this: assert type(id) in [type(None)]?

Answer (score 0):

`None` is not a type, it's a singleton sentinel value. `NoneType` is the type for `None`, but it's not exposed and shouldn't be used like that. `None` should only ever be tested with `is None`. You should also use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test types:

```
assert id is None or isinstance(id, (SafeString, int))
```

Also note that you shouldn't name your variables after builtins, `id` here is shadowing the builtin [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).